# Getting sitemesh to work with struts2

Tags: java, struts2, sitemesh

I'm trying to integrate sitemesh into my struts2 app, but i'm finding that it's not making any difference and isn't showing any errors (or anything sitemesh related at all) in the logs.

I've started by following all the documentation on the sitemesh site, had no luck, so now i'm trying to copy what's been done in the sitemesh-example download, to no avail. Any ideas would be great.

web-inf/web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
  <display-name>Sample</display-name>

  <filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>


  <filter>
    <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

web-inf/decorators.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<decorators defaultdir="/decorators">
    <decorator name="main" page="main.jsp">
          <pattern>*</pattern>
    </decorator>
</decorators>
```

web-inf/lib folder:

```
sitemesh-2.4.2.jar
sitemesh-decorator.tld
sitemesh-page.tld
```

decorators/main.jsp:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.opensymphony.com/sitemesh/decorator" prefix="decorator" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
 <title>
 My Site - <decorator:title default="Welcome!" />
 </title>
 <decorator:head />
</head>

 <body>
 <h1><decorator:title default="Welcome!" /></h1>
 <p><decorator:body /></p> 
 <p><small>
 (<a 
    href="?printable=true">printable version</a>)
    </small></p>
 </body>
</html>
```

Thanks guys

Comment: Can you provide the directory structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing I am seeing is here:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <decorators defaultdir="/decorators">
  <decorator name="main" page="main.jsp">
      <pattern>/*</pattern>
  </decorator>
 </decorators>
```

You need a /* not just a * as the pattern.

Maybe check the location of the decorators directory. Is it in the root of the app?

I also have this in my setup, I don't know if it makes a difference or not.

```
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
  </filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestions, the first one didn't help but the second one did! THanks a million!